# Tomcat - The requested resource () is not available. What can cause a .war file not to show/load?

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I've uploaded my .war file to /webapps.

I'm able to see it in the path, but if I got to //localhost:8080/vdma-vaadin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war it's not pulling up...

Any tips to look for?

Comment: Best tip ever: check the logs and paste the relevant errors here... Also, what does "not pulling up" mean? And why do you have the extension after the name of the WAR file?

Comment: you can always check http://localhost:8080/manager/html/ to see what application started.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to access the WAR directly. The WAR is just the web application archive. To access the web application try this:

```
http://localhost:8080/vdma-vaadin-0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

That is assuming there are no errors preventing your application from starting

Answer (score 1):

You should go to

```
http://localhost:8080/vdma-vaadin-0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/vdma-vaadin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to localhost:8080/folder_name_in_webapps_folder

Also there can be some problems about your code, you may check in tomcat/logs.